# Babashka - how to route stdout from external process call `clojure.java.shell/sh` to actual stdout

Tags: shell, clojure

With babashka, is there a way to route the stdout and stderr output of
from an external process call via something like `clojure.java.shell/sh`
directly to stdout?

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrap the `sh`-call into a `println`: `(println (shell/sh ...))`. This will print something like `{:out "" :err ""}`.

### Edit 20200708

As per the comment: Have a look at ProcessBuilder: https://github.com/borkdude/babashka/blob/master/examples/process_builder.clj

Comment: Thanks, but I actually want the stdout from the process to go directly to stdout.  This is for long-running processes, so I can see the status of the process while it's running rather than waiting till after.